# Count each row as 1 if there is a value in any column

Tags: excel

I have a table with data in a range from B2:F74 and I want to count once for each row if any column of that row is not blank. I found an easy way to do this for one row:

```
 =IFERROR(COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & "")/COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & ""),"")
```

and I know I can copy that down a column and add it together (which is what I'm currently using) but I was curious if there was an easy way to do this using a formula in only one cell.

A long way to do this would be:

```
 =IFERROR(COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & "")/COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & ""),"") + IFERROR(COUNTIF(B3:F3, "<>" & "")/COUNTIF(B3:F3, "<>" & ""),"") + ...
```

and adding it up individually. I tried

```
 =SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & "")/COUNTIF(B2:F2, "<>" & ""),""),IFERROR(COUNTIF(B74:F74, "<>" & "")/COUNTIF(B74:F74, "<>" & ""),""))
```

but that returns "1".

edit: fixed typo in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the non-volatile **array formula****:

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B2:F74<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:F74)^0))>0))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Just when I think I got a handle on these things, you prove me wrong.  I will remember this one.

Comment: @ScottCraner Your answer was 'a handle' on the problem! It's just that this is perhaps preferable due to its non-volatility.

Comment: That is the point, I hesitated even answering because of my disdain for volatile functions where non volatile can do the job.  I just could not come up with a way to do it without.  Then you come here and show a relatively simple solution that I kick myself for not knowing.  But know that I can see it AND comprehend how it works, I will steal it and use it myself.  I learnt myself my one thing today and am now going home.  And I thing this is the better answer and future readers should use this over mine.

Comment: Steal away, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

Use OFFSET to create a range of one row and iterate the rows, using SUMPRODUCT to tally the results:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B1,ROW($1:$73),0,1,5),"<>")>0))
```

[image]